# How can I create a dynamic WHERE statement for Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to be able to dynamically change the WHERE part based on the passed variable. for example

```
SELECT item,description
FROM TABLE WHERE department = :department
```

What I'm trying do is if the variable passed is 'NY' then I want to query states in CT,NJ and NY but if the variable is 'CA' then just query CA. 
Is there away I can use the CASE WHEN statement in the WHERE part?

I can't use SP or cursors just query.

Comment: Yes, you can use CASE WHEN in WHERE statement.

Answer (score 2):

That would be

```
where (department in ('CT', 'NJ', 'NY') and :department = 'NY')
   or (department = 'CA'                and :department = 'CA')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the logic you want is:

```
where (department in ('CT', 'NJ', 'NY') and :department = 'NY') or
      (department = :department)
```

This should work for any state, not just the four listed.

Comment: I'm afraid Oracle is not smart enough to use index in such case.

Comment: @ibre5041 - even if what you  say about indexes is true (I'm not convinced but don't feel like going to the trouble of putting together a proof), so what?  Not using an index is not necessarily a bad thing.  Oracle often correctly chooses a FTS even if an appropriate index is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this,

INSTR(DECODE(:department, 'CA', 'CA', 'NY', 'CT,NJ,NY'), department) > 0